# Expectation Inequality with indicator function

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inequality

When I read proof of Chebyshev's inequality, I came across the problem.

At first, [the proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) is :
\begin{align*}
P(|X-r|\geq k\sigma) &= E(\chi_{|X-\mu| \geq k\sigma})   \\
&= E(\chi_{\left( \frac{X-\mu}{k\sigma} \right)^2  \geq 1}) **from\_here**  \\
&\leq   E\left(   \left( \frac{X-\mu}{k\sigma} \right)^2   \right)  **to\_ here**  \\
&= \frac{1}{k^2} \frac{E((X-\mu)^2)}{\sigma^2}   \\
&= \frac{1}{k^2}
\end{align*}

As I make a point above, I cannot understand why the inequality holds.

Could you explain it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question has a purely visual answer posted under "Chebyshev's Theorem" at  http://www.quantdec.com/envstats/notes/class_06/properties.htm.

Comment: This is a little difficult for me... But Thank you very much. I will read it until I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality depends on the fact that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\chi_{y^2 \geq 1} \leq y^2.
$$
The proof is by cases. Suppose $y^2 < 1$. Then 
$$
\chi_{y^2 \geq 1} = 0 \leq y^2.
$$
Now suppose $y^2 \geq 1$. Then
$$
\chi_{y^2 \geq 1} = 1 \leq y^2.
$$
To obtain the inequality in your question, simply substitute $y = \frac{X - \mu}{k\sigma}$. Since this inequality holds for all values of $X$, it certainly holds in expectation.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify slightly the good answer above (+1 by the way), it's because, for any nonnegative random variable $Y$, 
$$
Y \ge Y \mathbb{1}(Y > 1) \ge \mathbb{1}(Y > 1).
$$
Then just take expectations on both sides of both inequalities.

Sorry to change your notation. I don't like the $\chi$ thing.